# Login request failed with using Google account

Tags: support, status-completed, ios-app, login

I made an account of Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange with my Google account just a few hours ago.

I do want to use this contents (Stack Overflow, something like that), so I try to log in with my iPhone and iPad, but when I try to log in using the Google account, the message which couldn't perform this request with my account is sent on and on.
How could I log in in the app Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange?

I'll write the message contains

> Request failed: Could not perform this request with your account, please try logging back in. If this persists, let us know on meta.

Comment: @RobertLongson Oh Now I see, Thanks :)